# JMS synchronous Request/Reply using temporary queue timed out reading

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I'm currently having a problem with jms synchronous request/reply approach, this is what happens:

1.) ProgramA create a jms message, a temporary queue and set it as a replyTo.

2.) ProgramB has a listener to the message created from ProgramA, process the message and reply to it. But ProgramB needs to communicate to a 3rd party web service that sometimes takes more than 10seconds to reply, and that is the problem I set the consumer to listen for 5000 (5s) and of course it will timeout afterwards. So the message is not received.

My observation:
1.) Even though ProgramA is done reading (no reply yet, at that instant I try to delete the temporary queue). It's not able to and ProgramB was still able to write to the reply queue, but nobody's going to read that message (too late).

When I try to change 5s to 20s listen time the problem was solved, but is it the right approach?

Also is it possible for the ProgramB to not try to write to the queue when ProgramA has stop reading?

Partial codes:

```
Destination replyQueue = send(jmsUtil, actionDTO);
SalesOrderResponseDTO responseDTO = readReply(jmsUtil, replyQueue, actionDTO);

public Destination send(JmsSessionUtil jmsUtil, SalesOrderActionDTO soDTO) {
    try {
        utx.begin();        
        jmsUtil.send(soDTO, null, 0L, 1, Long.parseLong(configBean.getProperty("jms.payrequest.timetolive")), true);
        utx.commit();
        return jmsUtil.getReplyQueue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }       
    }
    return null;
}

public SalesOrderResponseDTO readReply(JmsSessionUtil jmsUtil, Destination replyQueue, SalesOrderActionDTO actionDTO) {
    SalesOrderResponseDTO responseDTO = null;
    try {       
        utx.begin();

        responseDTO = (SalesOrderResponseDTO) jmsUtil.read(replyQueue);

        if (responseDTO != null) {
            // fires the response event
            SalesOrderResponsePayload eventPayload = new SalesOrderResponsePayload();
            eventPayload.setResponseDTO(responseDTO);
            responseEvent.fire(eventPayload);
        } else { // timeout
            ((TemporaryQueue) replyQueue).delete();
            jmsUtil.dispose();
        }
        utx.commit();
        return responseDTO;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }
    return responseDTO;
}

public String send(MessageDTO messageDTO,
            JMSQueueEnum resultNotificationQueue, Long parentProcessId,
            int JMSPriority, long timeToLive, boolean hasReply)
            throws JMSException, InvalidDTOException, NamingException {

    try {
        // Process optional parameters
        messageDTO.setResultNotificationQueue(resultNotificationQueue);
        messageDTO.setParentProcessId(parentProcessId);

        // Wrap MessageDTO in a JMS ObjectMessage
        ObjectMessage msg = MessageDTOHelper.serialize(session, messageDTO);
        msg.setJMSType(messageDTO.getClass().getSimpleName());
        msg.setStringProperty("DTOType", messageDTO.getClass()
                .getSimpleName());

        requestProducer = session.createProducer(queue);

        if (hasReply) {
            replyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
            replyConsumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue);     
            msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
        }

        if (JMSPriority > -1) {
            requestProducer.send(msg, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, JMSPriority,
                    timeToLive);
        } else {
            // Send the JMS message
            requestProducer.send(msg);
        }
        return msg.getJMSMessageID();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return null;
}

public MessageDTO read(Destination replyQueue) throws JMSException,
            NamingException {
    if (replyQueue instanceof Queue) {
        Message msg = replyConsumer.receive(20000);

        if (msg == null) {
            return null;
        }

        MessageDTO messageDTO = MessageDTOHelper
                .deserialize((ObjectMessage) msg);

        return messageDTO;
    } else {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual question here is whether you need synchronous or asynchronous communication.

I would always prefer asynchronous, and it seems from your question that there is no need for synchronous communication neither in your case. However, if there is some reason for synchronous then you are stuck with temporary queues - you'll have to specify timeout interval and you'll face problems expressed in your question. If Program A can wait, raise the timeout interval although that's far from optimal. As far as I know, there is no possibility for Program B to check if A still listens.

In case of asynchronous communication, you have (at least) two JMS options:

1. Using different message queues - Program A sends the message on Queue1 and finishes, but listens (e.g. through Message Driven Bean) on Queue2 where Program B puts its response when it's done. Small drawback is usage of one extra pair of producer and consumer.
2. Using same message queue - Program A and Program B both send and receive messages on Queue1, but with different message selector (see description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html)). Basically, message selectors will filter messages for specific listener and thus enable using same queue for bidirectional communication.

See also:

- [JMS Synchronous Message Consumption](http://effectivemessaging.blogspot.com/2009/01/jms-synchronous-message-consumption.html)

Comment: Hi @Miljen, unfortunately I'm stuck with synchronous because the source of the request must display the response as much as possible. I'm just concerned that I have to increase the wait time because the 3rd party could even respond in a minute and that would slow the system down when I have hundreds of concurrent users.

Comment: @czetsuya I understand. However, you still won't benefit from keeping Program A in blocked state. My suggestion: A sends the message with some correlation ID, displays the progress bar (or something similar) and finish. When Program B responds with exact correlation ID, activate Program A, remove the progress bar and show the response. Otherwise, you are risking resource shortage, because hundreds of concurrent users would mean hundreds of threads blocked and waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You could have A add a header to its message with the current timestamp + 5 secs. When B receives the response from the 3rd party,  if the current time is greater than the header,  it should drop the result and not send. You could use the time-to-live jms message property for this, although that is not its express purpose.